# is it will be a good practice to call API with json object as input parameter rather than NSDictionary.

Tags: objective-c, json, api, nsdictionary

is it will be a good practice to call API with json object as input parameter rather than NSDictionary.

Usually we used to send NSDictionary as input parameters. 
Is there any issue or performance improvement in mobile device or in server side

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense because these are two separate issues (the dictionary is how the structure is represented internally in your app; the JSON is merely the text representation of that dictionary that is used in transmission with many web services). Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Still now in mobile api services, we send data to the server as NSDictionary,  now the backend team wants to send data inside a dictionary ans JSON,  for example, Dict input :  @"Audi TT" : @"John",
    @"Audi Quattro (Black)" : @"Mary",
    @"Audi Quattro (Silver)" : @"Bill",
    @"Audi A7" : @"Bill"  But now they requesting to put same data like this  @"data" = @"{
    "Audi TT": "John",
    "Audi Quattro (Black)": "Mary",
    "Audi Quattro (Silver)": "Bill",
    "Audi A7": "Bill"
}"          is this will increase performance in server?

Comment: I assume you mean `@{@"data": @{@"Audi TT": @"John", @"Audi Quattro (Black)": @"Mary", @"Audi Quattro (Silver)": @"Bill", @"Audi A7": @"Bill" }`, which, when you convert it to JSON, would look like `{"data":{"Audi TT": "John", "Audi Quattro (Black)": "Mary", "Audi Quattro (Silver)": "Bill", "Audi A7": "Bill" }}`.

Comment: I still think you're conflating two very different issues. You've said repeatedly that you send data to server as `NSDictionary`. That's not possible. You generally create JSON representation of that dictionary and send that. (Or you could send plist or archive of the dictionary, but that would just be silly.) But you do not "send" `NSDictionary`. That makes no sense. Maybe you provide your network routines a dictionary, but it undoubtedly converts that for you. And it's not for efficiency's sake or anything like that. It's just how data is sent.

Comment: Now, in your last comment, you said you were sending simple dictionary and they're asking you to send that dictionary the value associated in yet another dictionary, keyed by `data`. You can do that, too, if needed. I'm not sure why you'd do that, but it's trivial to do, so I'm not sure why you're worrying about that if that's what they're asking for. You usually only do that "wrap it in a dictionary" trick if the thing being sent was actually an array and not a dictionary. But if they need it in that format, just do it and stop worrying about it. The efficiency difference in unobservable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a fine practice to take your Objective-C `NSDictionary`, use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert that to JSON (or use a library like AFNetworking that can do that for you) and send the JSON in the network request you send when calling your web service. You would generally not send the `NSDictionary` itself (e.g. a plist or keyed archiver). JSON is the *lingua franca* of web services. (XML is another very common format, though JSON is easier on the iOS side, IMHO.)

If you're building the network request yourself (e.g. building a `NSMutableURLRequest` to be sent using `NSURLSession`), remember to:

- set `HTTPMethod` to `@"POST"`;
- set the `HTTPBody` to be the JSON;
- set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/json`; and
- set the `Accept` HHTP header to indicate what format you're expecting the response to be (also likely `application/json`).